# Docker cloning - permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, docker

Ok I'm fairly new to UBUNTU but was just following some "simple steps", you know the sort that someone always claims will work out the box yet never ever does?

Anyway here's what I get:

```
# sudo docker run -i -v $PWD:/home/yyyy/work aaaa/bbbb git clone https://github.com/xxxx/yyyy.git 

Cloning into 'xxxx'...
/home/yyyy/work/yyyy/.git: Permission denied
```

What do i do?

Comment: What is `aaaa/bbbb` actually in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`docker run ... aaaa/bbb git` means running the aaaa/bbbb image (based probably on Ubuntu)

It depends on how that image was built (its Dockerfile): it the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir) was set to `/home/yyyy/work`, but [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/user) was set to another user, there would be a permission issue